# Read data from NSOperation subclass to multiple viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, nsoperation

I will explain scenario.

I have a `NSOperation` subclass. In this class , I am reading data from multiple bluetooth devices.
I am creating an object of `NSOperation` class in `ViewController` A and get data using `delegate` methods in `NSoperation` subclass.

Now, I want to read data from `Viewcontroller` B without creating an object of `NSoperation`.

Please check my `NSOperation` Subclass

**NOPerationSubclass.h**
    `

```
@protocol NOPerationSubclassDelegate`;

@interface NOPerationSubclass : NSOperation{

BOOL executing;
BOOL finished;
}


@property id<NOPerationSubclassDelegate> delegate;

 - (id)initWithConnectDevice:(ConnectDevice *)cDevice toPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral;

@end
@protocol NOPerationSubclassDelegate

-(void)updateUIFromOperation:(NOPerationSubclass *)operation;
@end
```

**NOPerationSubclass.m**

```
- (id)initWithConnectDevice:(ConnectDevice *)cDevice toPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral{

if (self = [super init]) {


    executing = NO;
    finished = NO;
    self.connectDevice = cDevice;
    [self.connectDevice setDelegate:self];
    self.connectedPeripheral = peripheral;

    dataDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


}
return self;
}

 -(BOOL)isConcurrent{
   return YES;
}
- (BOOL)isExecuting {
  return executing;
 }

 - (BOOL)isFinished {
   return finished;
 }

 -(void) terminateOperation {


[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
finished = YES;
executing = NO;
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
}

- (void)start {

@autoreleasepool {

    if (self.isCancelled){
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
        finished = YES;
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
        return;
    }
     timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self    selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];

}

-(void)timerFired:(id)sender{

if (self.isCancelled){

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    finished = YES;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    return;
 }

[connectDevice calldiscoverServicesForPeripheral:connectedPeripheral];



}


 -(void)getDataFromPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral Data:(NSString *)data{

[dataDic setValue:[peripheral.identifier UUIDString] forKey:@"identifier"];
[dataDic setValue:data forKey:@"data"];

[[[AppDelegate app] devicesDataArray] addObject:dataDic];


[(NSObject *)self.delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateUIFromOperation:) withObject:dataDic waitUntilDone:NO];

NSLog(@"PERIPHERAL DATA::+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%@",peripheral.name);
 }
```

And, I am calling this NSOpeartion class from ViewController A like this

```
  NOPerationSubclass *queue = [[NOPerationSubclass alloc] initWithConnectDevice:connectDevices   toPeripheral:peripheral];
  queue.delegate = self;

  [[[AppDelegate app] mainOperationQueue] addOperation:queue];
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: how are you navigating from your ViewController A to B?

Comment: Please checkk updated question Rob

Comment: PLease check updated question. I want to know get the data from NSoperation globally in project.

Comment: The easiest way to make data available globally is to post a custom notification to the `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]`. Any view controller that wants to be notified simply needs to add itself as an observer for the notification with that name. And remember to have the view controller remove itself as an observer when it is dismissed/deallocated.

Comment: Thanks alot Rob. I will try to implement that way. Please help is there any other way to implement.

Comment: If view controller B doesn't exist when you create the operation, then the notification technique is probably the logical choice. If view controller B does exist when you create the operation, you can use a delegate-protocol pattern or some block pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a shared instance class, this is what I always do:

**Database.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Database : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray* myTable;

+(Database*) sharedInstance;

@end
```

**Database.m**

```
#import "Database.h"

@implementation Database

Database* _db = nil;
+(Database*) sharedInstance {

    if (!_db)
        _db = [[Database alloc] init];

    return _db;

}

-(id) init {

    self = [super init];

    // Do loading here
    return self;

}

@end
```

Then whenever you want to access the data:

```
[Database sharedInstance].myTable;
```